# SpringBoot multiple @Configuration and SOAP clients

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ws

I have tried to follow this simple tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/, and it works.

I then try to connect to another SOAP service, with an additional `@Configuration` and client-class extending `WebServiceGatewaySupport`. It seems that both client-classes then use the same `@Configuration`-class, making the one I added first failing (unknown jaxb-context etc.). How can I ensure that the client-classes use the correct `@Configuration`-class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating @Bean in the @Configuration-classes that returns a `WebServiceTemplate`. That is, I don't use Spring's autoconfiguration mechanisms. I removed the `extend WebserviceGatewaySupport`, and use `@Autowired` to autowire the `WebserviceTemplateBean` bean created in the `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Hello thanks for you response but can you explain more in detail pls, if you can add the code could be so helpful thanks

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:** You have to match the name of the "marshaller()" method with the param variable name in your client configuration.

### Overriding bean definitions

What is happening is that both of your @Configuration clases are using the same bean name for the Jaxb2Marshaller, that is (using the spring example):

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() { //<-- that name
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();     
    marshaller.setContextPath("hello.wsdl");
    return marshaller;
}
```

There the "marshaller()" method name is the bean name that will be injected below in your client:

```
@Bean
public QuoteClient quoteClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) { //<-- used here
    QuoteClient client = new QuoteClient();
    client.setDefaultUri("http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx");
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return client;
}
```

If you use "marshaller()" for your second client, Spring overrides that bean definition. You could spot this in the log file, look for something like this:

```
INFO 7 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'marshaller'
```

### Solution

So to create more clients that have their own marshaller without colliding you need to have a @Configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientBConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerClientB() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("hello.wsdl");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientB clientB(Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerClientB) {
        ClientB client = new ClientB();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx");
        client.setMarshaller(marshallerClientB);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshallerClientB);
        return client;
    }

}
```

- More about bean overriding: https://blog.tratif.com/2018/03/08/when-two-beans-collide/
- Answer about spring boot @Configuration classes: [Why Spring Boot Application class needs to have @Configuration annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247487/why-spring-boot-application-class-needs-to-have-configuration-annotation)