# Why Spring Boot Application class needs to have @Configuration annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning about the Spring Framework but I can't understand what exactly the `@Configuration` annotation means and which classes should be annotated so. In the Spring Boot docs it is said that the Application class should be `@Configuration` class.

> Spring Boot favors Java-based configuration. Although it is possible
>   to call SpringApplication.run() with an XML source, we generally
>   recommend that your primary source is a @Configuration class.

Trying to learn about `@Configuration` I find that annotating a class with the `@Configuration` indicates that the class can be used by the Spring IoC container as a source of bean definitions.

If that is so then how is this application class a source of bean definitions?

```
@SpringBootApplication // same as @Configuration @EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);    
    }
}
```

I have pretty much understood most other basic concepts regarding Spring but I can't understand the purpose of `@Configuration` or which classes should be `@Configuration` classes? Can someone please help. Thanks !!

Comment: I think this thread needs to be reopened, as from the screenshot, you should always have the source param, otherwise it failed:
https://prnt.sc/gdFy9W1n0ncg

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You understood it right.

## @Configuration

`@Configuration` is an analog for  xml file. Such classes are sources of bean definitions by defining methods with the `@Bean` annotation.

`@Configuration` is:

- **not required**, if you already pass the annotated class in the `sources` parameter when calling the `SpringApplication.run()` method;
- **required**, when you don't pass the annotated class explicitly, but it's in the package that's specified in the `@ComponentScan` annotation of your main configuration class.

For readability, classes that are even explicitly passed as `sources` may anyway be annotated with `@Configuration` - just to show the intentions more clearly.

Your current class is not really source of bean definitions, because it doesn't have any, but if you had `@Bean` annotated methods, Spring would see them.

## @EnableAutoConfiguration

Can be used with or without `@Configuration`. It tells Spring to setup some basic infrastructure judging by what you have in the classpath. It's done by invoking a so called import class that's derived from the value of the `@Import` annotation that `@EnableAutoConfiguration` includes. Only one class should be annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, duplicating it doesn't do anything.

This answer may also be helpful to understand the Spring Boot initialization process: [Which piece of code in Spring Boot actually registers dispatcher servlet for SpringMVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214547/2816631)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and clear answer. It makes a lot of sense now. So is this annotation optional in this case? In fact I see this annotation being a bit overused such as in Spring Security, the SecurityConfig class is also annotated with @Configuration even though it doesn't have any beans http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/helloworld.html

Comment: You're right. That's optional, unless you want it to be auto-scanned (see my updated answer). That's the case with SecurityConfig - they annotated this just in case it'll be auto scanned.

Comment: @ArtemNovikov How and when will you consider/know when your application to be a full spring boot application?

Comment: I have tried without source passing in but it failed. I don't think this answer is more correct than the second one:
https://prnt.sc/x7Etuf-_CaNz
https://prnt.sc/gdFy9W1n0ncg

Comment: @Stan Hi, please note I didn't say `run()` can run without any arguments. Check carefully, I referred to Configuration vs EnableAutoConfiguration.

Comment: @ArtemNovikov but from the description, it really makes me think so. Can you give example on:`when you don't pass the annotated class explicitly`

Comment: @Stan I meant SpringApplication doesn't require @Configuration because that class is already passed in `run(...)`. It accepts array, but requires at least one item. Other classes that are not included in that array, must have @Configuration (and match @ComponentScan path) for them to be detected. Hope it's more clear now

Comment: @ArtemNovikov I am just about to comment. I kind of get it. You mean `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` need to be used together if it is not the SpringApplication class which will be run

Answer (score 16):

I think the main reason, why Spring Boot's `@SpringBootApplication` annotation automatically applies `@Configuration` is to allow to add bean definitions in the very same class. One of the main goals of Spring Boot is to allow you to create application fast and without extra movements. So by allowing you add bean definitions right into the Application's class, you don't need to create extra classes to hold your configuration. You have just 1 class and that's it.

Comment: I am afraid ur answer is also not anyhow correct. AS seen from the picture, even without annotation, the bean is still provisioned:
https://prnt.sc/PoHYAgutmNXh